# Ideas to speed up an order statistic calculation?

Tags: performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics

A toy example:

```
{n, top} = {25, 100};
mxs = RandomReal[{0, top}, n];

dist = UniformDistribution[Thread[{0, mxs}]];
result = Mean[OrderDistribution[dist, n]]
```

With these parameters this takes many minutes. My actual application will have $n$ in the hundreds and $top$ in the thousands (though the latter should not have much if any affect).

Ideas to speed this up?

Edit:
This seems to do the trick snappily, I'll self-answer with this if no one can beat it.

```
fn = With[{m = Sort@#, r = Range@Length@#}, 
    Tr[m^Reverse@r/((Last@r - r + 1) (Last@r - r + 2) Append[
         Reverse[FoldList[Times, Reverse[Rest@m]]], 1])]] &;
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for. Anyway, here's an approximation to the mean of the order statistic that takes a second or two to compute on my laptop:

```
Sort[#][[n]] & /@ RandomVariate[dist, 10^6] // Mean
```

Of course you could take fewer or more draws depending on the accuracy you want.

Comment: Thanks for this attempt. +1

Answer (score 2):

The OP edit answer does what I need pretty snappily.

For reference, the function and its usage is

```
fn = With[{m = Sort@#, r = Range@Length@#}, 
    Tr[m^Reverse@r/((Last@r - r + 1) (Last@r - r + 2) Append[
         Reverse[FoldList[Times, Reverse[Rest@m]]], 1])]] &;

fn@maxlist
```

where $maxlist$ is a list of the endpoints (maximums) of your uniform distributions.

For larger $n$ cases, the same but in log space can be nearly an order of magnitude faster:

```
fn2 = With[{m = Log[Sort@#], r = Range@Length@#}, 
    Tr[Exp[m*
        Reverse@r - (Log@(Last@r - r + 1) + Log@(Last@r - r + 2) + 
         Append[Reverse@Accumulate@Reverse@Rest@m, 0])]]] &;
```

E.G., calculating the millionth order statistic of a million uniform reals with endpoints between 0 and 1000 `{n,top}={1*^6,1000}` takes a couple of seconds on my laptop, with ~linear time vs $n$, compared to the much worse time vs $n$ growth of the intrinsic method (reaching a comparable time at $n$=16).

Performance comparison ($Mathematica$ intrinsic up to $n$=25 only):

[image]